# Jobs search seems to be ignoring distance

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, jobs, location

Yesterday I noticed that almost all of the jobs in my area disappeared from the usual Jobs search I do. Digging in further, I found that it is completely ignoring the "Distance" field in the search criteria.

Specifically, it is only finding jobs that are in exactly the zip code I put in, rather than jobs within 20, 50, or 100 miles of the zip code.

For example, searching for all jobs within 100 miles of Herndon, VA shows only the jobs in Herndon itself, even though there are jobs in Centreville, VA which is just 13 miles away:

[Jobs within 100 miles of Herndon, VA](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?location=herndon%2C%20va&range=100&distanceUnits=Miles)

[Jobs within 100 miles of Centreville, VA](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?location=20121&range=100&distanceUnits=Miles)

Did something change, am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed! Both your searches show a lot more jobs now :)

When you search for a large area, like "Virginia", we just search for everything inside it and ignore the distance. That way you don't see everything 100 miles from the center of the state, or 100 miles from every state border, or similar. We do that for any location larger than a city.

During some recent changes to how we store and handle locations, we accidentally changed a comparison so "larger than a city" became "city or larger" -- so it ignored the distance and only showed jobs *in the city itself*. I just changed it so that city searches will respect distances again.